# Best way to prototype web-based fine art startup?

Tags: prototype

I'd like to clarify the most efficient way to get a prototype for a web startup focused on helping people discover and securely acquire contemporary fine art and design objects.  My profile falls on the business side, although my past was more on the tech side.  So I'm familiar with programming & prototyping, but not in web apps.  Wondering if it's best to:

a) Get website package from hosting provider that would include database & commerce tools?  If so, will the amount of customization required (since this isn't a straight retail format) be so much that I'd be better off cobbling mine from scratch?

b) Build it using these tools: interface/front-end for website, product search engine (web app framework to pull & structure info from database), database itself to store records.  Because there are so many new tools involved, I worry that it could take me too long.  So, if this is the better option, I'd appreciate any recommended tools/templates to cut building time, (eg lighter weight plugin than having to learn all of RoR or Django in a short time).

Plus if all goes well, then I'd hire a developer, who would probably rebuild from scratch, rather than atop my rickety  prototype. The main aim now is to create proof of concept and get user feedback to determine if this is really worth pursuing.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  Having taken a look at Drupal & Joomla per your suggestions below, Wordpress also came to mind.   Since I'm quite familiar with it, I think I'll try first with WP and if unsatisfactory, try Drupal.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about anything programming-related.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you get a good Content Management System (CMS) and start there?  If you get a CMS that is well enough known you can hire people to work on it.  Plus since you are a programmer you can learn to work on it because of all the information available on the System.  (no particular order) DotNetNuke, Joomla, Drupal, and others.  You can also buy a CMS that comes with support if you are very unsure.

Since you use words like cobbling together a site and rickety prototype, I suggest you go with a well known and well established community CMS.

You can use these CMSes to build sites very quickly for a prototype.  CMSMadeSimple, for me, has been easy to prototype things with.

BTW, keep my name in the hat for developers.  :)

Comment: Might I recommend Orchard? http://orchardproject.net/ Its getting a lot of buzz right now, its a good combination between a CMS and a development platform. May be exactly what you need.

Comment: LOL, maybe not so dismal for the frontend since I'm fairly good @ GUI stuff. But "cobbling"/"rickety" for backend stuff as I haven't programmed in a while and never did web.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend a CMS. Learning how to utilize a full LAMP stack will take a while (plus, you can hire a developer to do that for you). CMSes like Drupal, DotNetNuke and Joomla are much easier to use.